# Refactoring code with a lot of "locks" to more lock-free code

Tags: c#, locking, task-parallel-library, lock-free, low-latency

**Upd** thanks to Matthew Watson for noticing and note that I plan to port my code to c++-linux so I prefer "platform-independent" code

My trading application is almost lock-free. The code below is the **only** place where I do use locks. Let me start with the code, it's pretty long but don't worry there are a lot of repeating parts so it's simple. I prefer to add all "repeating" parts to better demonstrate how my things work:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Iterate();
    }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

private void Iterate()
{
    bool marketDataUpdated = false;

    lock (ordersToRegisterLock)
    {
        if (ordersToRegister.Count > 0)
        {
            marketDataUpdated = true;
            while (ordersToRegister.Count > 0)
            {
                Order order = ordersToRegister.Dequeue();
                // Stage1, Process
            }
        }
    }

    lock (aggrUpdatesLock)
    {
        if (aggrUpdates.Count > 0)
        {
            marketDataUpdated = true;
            while (!aggrUpdates.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                var entry = aggrUpdates.Dequeue();
                // Stage1, Process
            }
        }
    }

    lock (commonUpdatesLock)
    {
        if (commonUpdates.Count > 0)
        {
            marketDataUpdated = true;
            while (!commonUpdates.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                var entry = commonUpdates.Dequeue();
                // Stage1, Process
            }
        }
    }

    lock (infoUpdatesLock)
    {
        if (infoUpdates.Count > 0)
        {
            marketDataUpdated = true;
            while (!infoUpdates.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                var entry = infoUpdates.Dequeue();
                // Stage1, Process
            }
        }
    }

    lock (tradeUpdatesLock)
    {
        if (tradeUpdates.Count > 0)
        {
            marketDataUpdated = true;
            while (!tradeUpdates.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                var entry = tradeUpdates.Dequeue();
                // Stage1, Process
            }    

        }
    }

    if (marketDataUpdated)
    {
        // Stage2 !
        // make a lot of work. expensive operation. recalculate strategies, place orders etc.
    }
}

private readonly Queue<Order> ordersToRegister = new Queue<Order>();
private readonly object ordersToRegisterLock = new object();

private readonly Queue<AggrEntry> aggrUpdates = new Queue<AggrEntry>();
private readonly object aggrUpdatesLock = new object();

private readonly Queue<CommonEntry> commonUpdates = new Queue<CommonEntry>();
private readonly object commonUpdatesLock = new object();

private readonly Queue<InfoEntry> infoUpdates = new Queue<InfoEntry>();
private readonly object infoUpdatesLock = new object();

private readonly Queue<TradeEntry> tradeUpdates = new Queue<TradeEntry>();
private readonly object tradeUpdatesLock = new object();


    public void RegistorOrder(object sender, Gate.RegisterOrderArgs e)
    {
        lock (ordersToRegisterLock)
        {
            ordersToRegister.Enqueue(e.order);
        }
    }

    public void TradeUpdated(object sender, Gate.TradeArgs e)
    {
        lock (tradeUpdatesLock)
        {
            foreach (var entry in e.entries)
            {
                tradeUpdates.Enqueue(entry);
            }
        }
    }

    public void InfoUpdated(object sender, Gate.InfoArgs e)
    {
        lock (infoUpdatesLock)
        {
            foreach (var entry in e.entries)
            {
                infoUpdates.Enqueue(entry);
            }
        }
    }

    public void CommonUpdated(object sender, Gate.CommonArgs e)
    {
        lock (commonUpdatesLock)
        {
            foreach (var entry in e.entries)
            {
                commonUpdates.Enqueue(entry);
            }
        }
    }

    public void AggrUpdated(object sender, Gate.AggrArgs e)
    {
        lock (aggrUpdatesLock)
        {
            foreach (var entry in e.entries)
            {
                aggrUpdates.Enqueue(entry);
            }
        }
    }
```

In my code I have two stages. `Stage1` is update stage and `Stage2` is working stage. I need to switch between these two stages as fast as possible, like that:

- any updates? no
- any updates? no
- any updated? yes, order updated! apply update, do `Stage2`
- any updates? no
- any updates? yes, order need to be registered! apply update, do `Stage2`
- any updates? yes, trade occured, apply update, do `Stage2`

In `Stage2` I should not update, but should keep "collecting" updates so I can apply they later.

And important thing - this is very latency-critical code so I agree to "spent" one core for having **minimal** latency! So when **any** update occure I need to process it **asap** and perform `Stage2`.

So I hope now it's clear what I need to achieve and it's clear how I have implemented that. Now it's time to discuss how good my code is. I do see several potential problems:

- a lot of locks! can it be replaced with some "lock-free" code? spinlock with CAS or something?
- occupy 100% of CPU core, can I save some CPU resources **without affecting latency**?
- can/should I tell .NET to use "dedicated" core (set task affinity?) to avoid extra "switch"?
- I *add* to Queues from one thread and I *read* Queues from another thread. Could it be a problem? If adding and reading to a Queue is volatile? Is it possible that my *reading* thread will not see update from a Queue because cache-update problem?

Any suggestions how to improve what I wrote are welcome, thanks!

**upd** partly solved - as I understand I better to replace queries to lock-free (likely ring-buffer based?) queries.. i think i will use c++ version of disruptor later. Also I've used this article http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2010/03/08/Running_NET_threads_on_selected_processor_cores and replaced Task with a Thread running on the "fixed" core, however i'm still using "busy-spin", probably I should use something smarter?

Comment: If you're locking for thread-safe queue access, try to use [ConcurrentQueue<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) (.NET 4.0+). For further reading see: - [ConcurrentQueue in a nutshell](http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-system_collections_concurrent_concurrentqueue) (brief description)
- [ConcurrentQueue vs. Queue](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/06/07/c-system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-vs.-queue.aspx) (shows that CQ is faster than Q+Lock)

Comment: Yes, this is designed for precisely this kind of thing. Also, check out BlockingCollection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx

Comment: Lock-free code increases latency. You are looking for wait-free code.

Comment: no need to use `ConcurrentQueue` in this my very simple case. just `Queue` is enough and most likely it would be faster. at least because I obtain lock one time and add a lot of elements, what is not possible with `ConcurrentQueue`

Comment: and question is not about Queue vs ConcurrentQueue. it more about avoiding locks and improving latency. definitely `ConcurrentQueue` can not improve latency.

Comment: @javapowered: I would first switch to CQ as first refactoring stage. Than go further and find more subjects for refactoring.

Comment: @abatishchev why do I need to switch to `ConcurrentQueue`? to make my code slower?

Comment: @javapowered: ConcurrentQueue is *faster* than ordinal Queue with locking

Comment: @abatishchev note that I need to port to Linux soon so i would prefer something portable. if ConcurrentQueue is faster than what it use inside and can I just use the same in my code?

Comment: another problem with `ConcurrentQueue` is that i can `Enqueue` only one object. But i need to `Enqueue` array of objects. in the receive side i need to Dequeue "array or nothing". Otherwise my data will be inconsistent. But probably I can just create object that contains array of objects. Then I can switch to ConcurrentQueue...

Comment: Well then then item type of the queue is an array of objects. If you want to treat it as a single entity, queue it as a single entity. Simples! Like you said. :)

Comment: Seems that CQ is [already implemented](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs) in Mono

Comment: @MatthewWatson that will work. but that will not be portable to c++-linux I guess. So anyway I have to implement some "low-level" synchronization myself :) I'm not sure that I will use Mono. In my case I guess it should be comparatively easy to implement something that is not slower than ConcurrentQueue but much more portable to c++?

Comment: So, only NOW are you mentioning that you want to rewrite this all in C++? Thanks for wasting all our time.

Comment: Watch out folks. He wants to rewrite this all in C++ apparently, but he didn't want to tell us. Seems he'd rather we waste our time giving incorrect answers.

Comment: @MatthewWatson well I'm sorry, i didn't realized that my question is so platform-specific. I was thinking it more about "processor afinity" low-level lock and about other "platform-independent" things.

Comment: Please describe your code more in general terms. Looks like you're performing sync pooling/throttling. Instead I would switch to async processing based on notifications.

Comment: sorry guys yes I would prefer solutions that easy to port to c++ - linux in future.

Comment: Actually, there are a few ConcurrentQueue implementations in C++ floating around the 'Net, so it could still be worth using that! For example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23317/Lock-Free-Queue-implementation-in-C-and-C

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks I will consider using one of the lock-free ConcurrentQueue implementations, it's a good suggestion to avoid locks i think! as a first step I will try to profile "average" time I currently spent for one cycle so I have some number to compare. However my question contains several more points so I still waiting for someone to answer other points.

Comment: Maybe look into some kind of optimistic locking mechanism, where you allow a client to do multiple operations in a row if it is constantly grabbing and releasing locks. Strictly speaking you don't really need a hard enqueue lock, you could maybe have multiple queues and signal which one was used.

Comment: @aggaton signal will add latency i would prefer something faster, spin-wait for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code below, you are no longer locked during "stage 1" processing:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Iterate();
    }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);


private void Iterate()
{
    bool marketDataUpdated = false;

    foreach (Order order in ordersToRegister)
    {
        marketDataUpdated = true;
        // Stage1, Process
    }

    foreach (var entry in aggrUpdates)
    {
        marketDataUpdated = true;
        // Stage1, Process
    }

    foreach (var entry in commonUpdates)
    {
        marketDataUpdated = true;
        // Stage1, Process
    }

    foreach (var entry in infoUpdates)
    {
        marketDataUpdated = true;
        // Stage1, Process
    }

    foreach (var entry in tradeUpdates)
    {
        marketDataUpdated = true;
        // Stage1, Process
    }

    if (marketDataUpdated)
    {
        // Stage2 !
        // make a lot of work. expensive operation. recalculate strategies, place orders etc.
    }
}

private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Order> ordersToRegister = new ConcurrentQueue<Order>();

private readonly ConcurrentQueue<AggrEntry> aggrUpdates = new ConcurrentQueue<AggrEntry>();

private readonly ConcurrentQueue<CommonEntry> commonUpdates = new ConcurrentQueue<CommonEntry>();

private readonly ConcurrentQueue<InfoEntry> infoUpdates = new ConcurrentQueue<InfoEntry>();

private readonly ConcurrentQueue<TradeEntry> tradeUpdates = new ConcurrentQueue<TradeEntry>();

    public void RegistorOrder(object sender, Gate.RegisterOrderArgs e)
    {
        ordersToRegister.Enqueue(e.order);
    }

    public void TradeUpdated(object sender, Gate.TradeArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var entry in e.entries)
        {
            tradeUpdates.Enqueue(entry);
        }
    }

    public void InfoUpdated(object sender, Gate.InfoArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var entry in e.entries)
        {
            infoUpdates.Enqueue(entry);
        }
    }

    public void CommonUpdated(object sender, Gate.CommonArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var entry in e.entries)
        {
            commonUpdates.Enqueue(entry);
        }
    }

    public void AggrUpdated(object sender, Gate.AggrArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var entry in e.entries)
        {
            aggrUpdates.Enqueue(entry);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, well that's what i've done. I'm still locking but inside ConcurrentQueue. That would be portability issue when i decide to port to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that might be more portable.  Hope it helps.

```
public class SafeQueue<T> : Queue<T>
{
    public T SafeDequeue()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            return (Count > 0) ? Dequeue() : null;
        }
    }

    public void SafeEnqueue(T entry)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Enqueue(entry);
        }
    }
}

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Iterate();
    }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);


private void Iterate()
{
    bool marketDataUpdated = false;

    while ((Order order = ordersToRegister.SafeDequeue()) != null)
    {
        marketDataUpdated = true;
        // Stage1, Process
    }

    while ((var entry = aggrUpdates.SafeDequeue()) != null)
    {
        marketDataUpdated = true;
        // Stage1, Process
    }

    while ((var entry = commonUpdates.SafeDequeue()) != null)
    {
        marketDataUpdated = true;
        // Stage1, Process
    }

    while ((var entry = infoUpdates.SafeDequeue()) != null)
    {
        marketDataUpdated = true;
        // Stage1, Process
    }

    while ((var entry = tradeUpdates.SafeDequeue()) != null)
    {
        marketDataUpdated = true;
        // Stage1, Process
    }

    if (marketDataUpdated)
    {
        // Stage2 !
        // make a lot of work. expensive operation. recalculate strategies, place orders etc.
    }
}

private readonly SafeQueue<Order> ordersToRegister = new SafeQueue<Order>();

private readonly SafeQueue<AggrEntry> aggrUpdates = new SafeQueue<AggrEntry>();

private readonly SafeQueue<CommonEntry> commonUpdates = new SafeQueue<CommonEntry>();

private readonly SafeQueue<InfoEntry> infoUpdates = new SafeQueue<InfoEntry>();

private readonly SafeQueue<TradeEntry> tradeUpdates = new SafeQueue<TradeEntry>();

    public void RegistorOrder(object sender, Gate.RegisterOrderArgs e)
    {
        ordersToRegister.SafeEnqueue(e.order);
    }

    public void TradeUpdated(object sender, Gate.TradeArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var entry in e.entries)
        {
            tradeUpdates.SafeEnqueue(entry);
        }
    }

    public void InfoUpdated(object sender, Gate.InfoArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var entry in e.entries)
        {
            infoUpdates.SafeEnqueue(entry);
        }
    }

    public void CommonUpdated(object sender, Gate.CommonArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var entry in e.entries)
        {
            commonUpdates.SafeEnqueue(entry);
        }
    }

    public void AggrUpdated(object sender, Gate.AggrArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var entry in e.entries)
        {
            aggrUpdates.SafeEnqueue(entry);
        }
    }
```